# Bootstrap Mobile Nav on Lumia 930 / 1520

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a heck of a time displaying the bootstrap mobile nav on a Nokia Lumia 930 and 1520 when it is in landscape mode. I even tried some of the starter bootstrap templates and they don't render the mobile nav either you get the desktop nav in landscape from these larger resolution WinMo devices.

Any idea how I can target these from a media query or something. At this point I would even take a JS method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else that finds this, this is what fixed it for me

```
<script>
  (function() {
   if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style &&
   (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/) ||
   navigator.userAgent.match(/ZuneWP7/) ||
   navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/))) {
   var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
   msViewportStyle.appendChild(
   document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
   );
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
   }
  })();    
</script>
```

I found this at the bottom of this article http://www.markadrake.com/blog/2013/05/31/responsive-design-concerns-for-windows-phone-and-ie-compatibility-modes/ after trying a bunch of different of these types scripts

Answer (score 0):

IE Mobile 10 does not fire media queries as specified, it interrupts device width differently.

Add this to as the first JS you call...

```
(function() {
    if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
        );
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I have tried this at the bottom of my scripts file but it didnt do anything. I will start it at the top. Should i put it in the head like before i call jQuery and Bootstrap.js? Also i am not 100% sure that is true, because in portrait mode the phone does fire media queries. Everything displays correct it is ONLY in landscape mode. Also worth mentioning all the other Lumia Phone work in both portrait and landscape. This one just seems to have a HUGE resolution and is un affected by the media quires.